# Updatepanel not updating the mutliple labels in multiple panels

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

Okay, hopefully a simple one,

Labels are not updating here when update is called on each update panel and only work when finished,

script manage is no the master page allowing for partial rendering already as well. but still not working, any ideas? Is what i'm trying to do not correct?

please don't just post a link, actully show me where i'm going wrong. is my understaing of update panels not correct? How can I achieve this? Thanks

```
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" OnClick="button1_Click" />
    </div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1UP1" Text="This is the first label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <%--        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="button1" />
        </Triggers>--%>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UP2" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1UP2" Text="This is the second label label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UP3" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1UP3" Text="This is the third label label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>  
</asp:Content>


 protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["el"] = methodone();
        label1UP1.Text = ViewState["el"].ToString();
        label1UP1.DataBind();
        up1.Update();


        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        string label2 = methodtwo();
        label1UP2.Text = label2.ToString();
        label1UP2.DataBind();
        UP2.Update();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

        string label3 = methothree();
        label1UP3.Text = label3.ToString();
        label1UP3.DataBind();
        UP3.Update();
    }
```

Comment: Can you wrap the button in an UpdatePanel and test?

Comment: @Zee sorry what do you mean ? the button in a separate panel of its own ? update manually as well ?

Comment: yes in its own update panel, don't update it manually.

Comment: done that @zee - now the page comeback immediately and then all the results in one go
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" OnClick="button1_Click" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: are you trying to update the three labels with a delay?

Comment: yes, in actual fact my function takes along time to run but this way i want to update the results I have, as I go along the delay is just to simulate what would happen. @Zee

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242870/discussion-between-zee-and-altf4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

1. Do a postback three times, with a delay using javascript
   Eg:

   `

   ```
       <script>
      function callBackend(labelValue){
       document.getElementById("HLabelName").value = labelValue;
       __doPostBack("HLabelName", ""); //This causes a postback
     } 

      </script>

   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HLabelName"  OnValueChanged="HLabelName_OnValueChanged" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
   ```

`
2. Each time set a hiddenfield value to identify the label to update
3. In the backend event, get the hiddenfield value and update the corresponding label

In the backend:

```
    //This triggers the first event
     protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       //Then call JS function to update label1
       //This triggers the second event
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "CallLabel3", "setTimeout(callBackend('label2'), 3000)", true);
     }

  protected void HLabelName_OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (this.HLabelName.Value)
        {
            case "label2":
                //Update Label 2 here Value here
                
               //This triggers the third event
               //Then call JS function to update label3
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "CallLabel3", "setTimeout(callBackend('label3'), 3000)", true);
                break;
            case "label3":
                //Update Label 3 here
                break;
        }
    }
```

This should do the trick for you

Comment: Either what i've done is incorrect or this method doesn't seem to solve my issue. :(

Comment: @AltF4_ Hi posted a different method, try this